# jQuery Mobile showing a border/outline around image background

Tags: image, jquery-mobile

I'm using the jQuery Mobile to build the mobile website and i have a listview that showing the icons for each menu on the landing page.

I display the icon via background-image with background-position on img tag (using sprite icon):

```
.ui-li-icon {top:10px;left:25px;}
.iconhome {background: transparent url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat;margin:7px 15px 0 0;width:21px;height:22px;}
#i-travel {background-position:-4px -3px;}
```

And for listview:

```
<ul data-theme="c" data-role="listview">
<li><a href="step1.html"><img class="iconhome ui-li-icon" id="i-travel"></img>Travel and Fly<br><span class="small gray">Buy Travel Insurance</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem: it has an outline that I can't get rid from it eventhough I added border:0 / border:none / outline:none .. To my surprise, when I change and look around with border-radius, it's changed but not to normal border css property.

How I can remove the border/outline around my background-image?

*Added: I realized it's only happen on **background-image property on img tag**. For div tag (using background-image) or img tag (with no background-image), it doesn't show any border/outline.

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-style: none` to the css for `img` tags.

```
img {
   border-style: none;
}
```

Should override anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I would use class - the element that is causing the issue. I would open up firebug in chrome & firebug - and view and inspect the offending element and see what properties are being inherited.

When JQM renders lists it's not just lists but spans inside to create the right effect. If any of these elements are wrapping around the image it **WILL** cause an issue in selecting your specific css.

This is the process I use to get over these humps.

1. I would try to get rid of the border inline on the element using
   firebug to see if that changes. I would also use firebug to see if elements are inheriting like I suspect.
2. I would add the property background-image:none, border:none; outline:none; as an inline style to your
   particular element.
3. Lastly, I've discovered sometimes, no matter what you do, you can't override the primary style. As a last resort I use !important  background-image:none !important; on the specific element.

Comment: apparently i'm using the background-image (the one that you see background: transparent url(image.png) no-repeat).. if i declare the background-image: none then i can't use the property background: url() anymore..